# Is it possible to compare more than two kernels executions at a time in Compute Prof (OpenCL/CUDA)

Tags: cuda, compare, opencl, profiler

Is it possible to compare more than two kernel executions at a time in Compute Prof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if they are ran by the same process. They will show up in the final log file.